# GSON throwing “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY”?

Tags: android, json, json.net, gsoap

i have following JSON Response .

```
  {"message":"[{\"first_name\":\"Sushant\",\"last_name\":\"Bhatnagar\",\"receiver_id\":\"19\",\"docket_number\":\"Test12\",\"status\":\"open\"}]","code":200,"format":"json"}
```

and I have create two classes for parse it as below :-

```
     public class JsonResponse implements Serializable {

public String code;
public String format;
public List<Message> message;
```

}

public class Message implements Serializable{

```
public String first_name;
public String last_name;
public String receiver_id;
public String docket_number;
public String status;
```

}

Using GSOAP for parse json , getting above error . Code for parse JSON is :-

```
         public static JsonResponse readDockets(String mobileNumber) {
    JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String service = "http://api.pod.iamwhiney.com:8994/api.php?path=/deliveryRecord/refresh/"+"9968395206";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(service);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {            

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
            Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponseStream);               
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            res = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, JsonResponse.class);

        } else {

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSon` string should be in this format:

```
{
  sections: 
      [
          {
             "SectionId": 1,
             "SectionName": "Android"
          }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using Gson, as Android has it's own build in JSON parser. As for the error you're getting...it's because the JSON you're parsing is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. I'm not quite sure what @Yaqub is looking at, but your JSON response should be as follows:

```
{"message":    
    {"first_name":"Sushant",
     "last_name":"Bhatnagar".....
     "status":"open"
    },"code":"200","format":"json"}
```

That is, without the [ ] around the content, as this tells the JSON parser that it's a JSON Array with only 1 index, whereas you clearly want a single JSON Object instead. The above JSONString will allow you to parse it where you can get a JSONObject from the 'message' tag.

**Note**: I've removed the escapes as I wanted to run my edit through a parser, but you could easily add these back in and it should still work.

**Note**: the `"code":200` in your original JSON needs to be `"code":"200"` otherwise you'll get another error there